# Access to an array inside json structure by value

Tags: json, typescript

How I can access to the  `models array` when I have only the information "Bridgestone" or "Continental". I think that should works with `Object.keys()` and `find()` but all my tries didn't worked. I think the trick is to get the key and with this key you can iterate with `forEach()` the models.

```
json_structure = { 
   "tyres":[ 
      { 
         "manufacture":"Bridgestone",
         "models":[ 
            "Potenza",
            "Turanza"
         ]
      },
      { 
         "manufacture":"Continental",
         "models":[ 
            "Allseasonconta",
            "Winter Contact"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `find` method to find a manufacture by its name, and then get the models array out of it:

```js
const jsonStructure = { 
   "tyres":[ 
      { 
         "manufacture":"Bridgestone",
         "models":[ 
            "Potenza",
            "Turanza"
         ]
      },
      { 
         "manufacture":"Continental",
         "models":[ 
            "Allseasonconta",
            "Winter Contact"
         ]
      }
   ]
}

const getModelsByManufactureName = data => name => {
  const manufacture = data.tyres.find(val => val.manufacture === name)
  if (!manufacture) return manufacture
  return manufacture.models
}

console.log(getModelsByManufactureName(jsonStructure)('Bridgestone'))
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without an explicit loop, but knowledge of the overall structure is still necessary:

```js
json_structure.tyres.filter(o => o.manufacture == "Continental")[0].models
```

So the first step is to get to the `"tyres"` portion which is an array and then `filter` by `"manufacture"`.

Then you can look at the first record (assuming `"Continental"` is unique and there is the `"models"` object.

Another more explicit way to do this would be similar to what you were proposing:

```
model = {};

json_structure.tyres.forEach(function(o) {
  if(o.manufacture == "Continental") {
    model = o.models; return;
  }
})
```

`model` should contain the model information.